# There are some strange symbols in the Nuxt source code, can you tell me what this is

Tags: nuxt.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtU1W.png)

can you tell me what this is

Answer (score 1):

Lodash templates - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template

These are used for example in nuxt modules - https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules#template-plugins